# Finding all primes of a particular sequence

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in C that finds all sequences of consecutive 5 digit prime numbers (a, b, c, d, e, f ), in such a way that b = a + 2, c = b + 4, d = c + 6, e = d + 8, and f = e + 10.

My solution is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


bool IsPrime(int x){

    for (int i = 2; i < x; i++){
        if (x % i == 0 && x != i) return false;
    }
    return true;
}           


int main(void){

    int a,b,c,d,e,f;


    for (int i = 10000; i < 99999; i++){
        if (IsPrime(i) == true && IsPrime(i + 2) == true && IsPrime(i + 6) == true && IsPrime(i + 12) == true && IsPrime(i + 20) == true && IsPrime(i + 30)){
            a = i;
            b = i + 2;
            c = i + 6;
            d = i + 12;
            e = i + 20;
            f = i + 30;
            printf("%i %i %i %i %i %i \n", a, b, c, d, e, f);
            a, b, c, d, e, f = 0;
        }
    }



// end
}
```

which gives the following output:

> 13901 13903 13907 13913 13921 13931
>
> 21557 21559 21563 21569 21577 21587
>
> 26681 26683 26687 26693 26701 26711
>
> 28277 28279 28283 28289 28297 28307
>
> 31247 31249 31253 31259 31267 31277
>
> 33617 33619 33623 33629 33637 33647
>
> 55661 55663 55667 55673 55681 55691
>
> 68897 68899 68903 68909 68917 68927
>
> 97367 97369 97373 97379 97387 97397

However, the correct solution is apparantly:

> ```
> 13901   13903   13907   13913   13921   13931
>
> 21557   21559   21563   21569   21577   21587
>
> 28277   28279   28283   28289   28297   28307
>
> 55661   55663   55667   55673   55681   55691
>
> 68897   68899   68903   68909   68917   68927
> ```

As you can see, my solution (the first output set above), contains all the prime sequences in the correct solution (the second output set above), plus a few additional solutions. I have been advised that my solution has redundant prime numbers between a, b, c, d, e and f, and that is why the proper solution contains less solutions. Can someone explain why some of the rows in my output are redundant (they seem to fit the primary condition of the question)? Also, how can I eliminate the redundant sets from my solution?

Comment: you've got the answer, here's an illustration: `26699` is also a prime. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any `i`, you are checking the following for primality:

```
i
i + 2
i + 6
i + 12
i + 20
i + 30
```

If all of these are prime, it still does not satisfy the predicate unless you also establish that these are *consecutive* primes. Thus you need to check that the numbers `i + 4`, `i + 8`, etc. (up through `i + 28`) are *not* prime. (You don't need to check `i + an_odd_number` because those can never be prime if `i` and `i + 2` are both prime.)

Comment: @Tangler That's grossly inefficient. See my answer for a much faster (and simpler) way.

Comment: @JimBalter I understand this, however im very new to programming in general and i'm just trying to get correct outputs most of the time. I did change 'i < x' to 'i*i < x' however, which has made it a lot more efficient, bringing iterations down from around 100k to around 300.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Fixed

bool IsPrime(int x){
    //some changes to make the code run faster.
    if (x < 2) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i*i < x; ++i)
    {
        if (x % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}           


int main(void){

    int a,b,c,d,e,f;


    for (int i = 10001; i < 99999; i+=2){
        //continue for all the wrong cases.
        if (!IsPrime(i)) continue;
        if (!IsPrime(i+2)) continue;
        if (!IsPrime(i+6)) continue;
        if (!IsPrime(i+12)) continue;
        if (!IsPrime(i+20)) continue;
        if (!IsPrime(i+30)) continue;

        //Those checks if you need to validate no primes in the middle.
        if (IsPrime(i+4)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+8)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+10)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+14)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+16)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+18)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+22)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+24)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+26)) continue;
        if (IsPrime(i+28)) continue;

        //If we got here, all is good.
        a = i;
        b = i + 2;
        c = i + 6;
        d = i + 12;
        e = i + 20;
        f = i + 30;
        printf("%i %i %i %i %i %i \n", a, b, c, d, e, f);
    }

// end
}
```

**an even faster way to do that would be to save in an array (or any other way) the last 15 odd numbers you checked for "primeness" and then only check if the sequence is the right one. because in the current approach you can check if a number is prime up to 15 times.**

Answer (score 0):

You're paying no attention to the requirement that the primes are consecutive, and your code is much slower than it need be. Keep a queue of the last 6 primes, inserting each prime at the end of the queue and dropping the first one ... this can be easily done with a circular array. Each time you insert a prime, check whether the difference conditions apply ... if so you have a solution.

For your IsPrime routine, you only need to check up to the square root of x, and you don't need to check i != x since it's always less.

Here's a working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static inline int next(int i)
{
    return (i + 1) % 6;
}

static void check(int* p, int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, x = next(x))
        if (p[next(x)] - p[x] != (i+1) * 2)
            return;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("%d%c", p[x = next(x)], i == 5? '\n' : ' ');
}

static bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 3; i*i < n; i += 2)
        if ((n % i) == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int cp[6] = { 0 };
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 10001; i <= 99999; i += 2)
        if (isPrime(i))
        {
            cp[x] = i;
            check(cp, x = next(x));
        }

    return 0;
}
```

An even faster solution would use a precomputed table of primes ... use

```
static int primes[316]; // sqrt(99999)
static int nprimes;

static bool isPrime(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nprimes; i++)
        if ((n % primes[i]) == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

and add

```
for (int n = 3; nprimes < 316; n += 2)
    if (isPrime(n))
        primes[nprimes++] = n;
```

before the loop in main.

For a general solution, with very large primes, you can produce the first N primes with the [Segmented Sieve of Erastothenes](http://www.ieeta.pt/~tos/software/prime_sieve.html).

Comment: this problem screams for the segmented sieve of Eratosthenes solution, in general. :) But for 99999 upper limit, it doesn't matter. -- OP must keep the "previous primes" just up to 316. You didn't specify this exactly. :)